# If cell value in column <> certain text then cell value splits with text to columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to determine if the cell values in column H (number of rows varies per file) are "Words" or "Words2". The cells that do not contain "Words" or "Words2" are split into separate columns based on a space delimiter while those that do contain "Words" and "Words2" have no change. Currently my code does not separates any cells. I am new to using Dim as Range and InStr and I am not entirely sure if it is most efficient to use them. I have tried multiple variations of the code to no avail, as well. ARGNAME is each cell in column H (or at least that is what I am aiming for).

For example: H1 = "Words" no change, and H2 = "Words I don't care about" splits into H2:L2

```
Sub WordSplit
    Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim SrchRng As Range, ARGNAME As Range
        Set SrchRng = Range("H1:H" & lastRow)
        For Each ARGNAME In SrchRng
            If InStr(1, ARGNAME.Value, "Words") Or InStr(1, ARGNAME.Value, "Words2") < 0 _
            Then Columns("H:H").TextToColumns Destination:=Range ("H1"), DataType _
                :=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1)),TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            End If
        Next ARGNAME
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WordSplit1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim srchRng As Range, argName As Range
    Set srchRng = ws.Range("H1:H" & lastRow)

    For Each argName In srchRng

        If InStr(1, argName.Value2, "Words") = 0 And _
           InStr(1, argName.Value2, "Words2") = 0 Then

                argName.TextToColumns Destination:=argName, _
                                      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
                                      Space:=True, _
                                      FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1)), _
                                      TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

---

Your initial code was on the right track, but I updated the following:

- Used `Option Explicit` at the top of the module
- Fully qualified all ranges with a specific sheet (CodeName: Sheet1)
- Fixed code indentation to make it easier to read
- Issues related to `InStr`:

  - It only returns positive integers ( >= 0 )
  - All `InStr` expressions must be checked for return values (not just the last one)
  - If the cell doesn't contain "Words" AND it doesn't contain "Words2"
  - Initial If:
  - `If InStr(1, ARGNAME.Value, "Words") Or InStr(1, ARGNAME.Value, "Words2") < 0`
  - becomes:
  - `If InStr(1, argName.Value, "Words") = 0 And InStr(1, argName.Value, "Words2") = 0`
- Next issue:

  - The `If` statement is separated onto the second line in an invalid location (syntax error)
  - `") < 0 _
        Then Columns("H:H")`
  - Your next line splits all cells in column H containing multiple words for every cell not containing "Words" or "Words2"

---

The code implies that there is no data beyond column H

Comment: Ah, I separated the `InStr` statements and updated them to `And` instead of `Or` as well as the range on my `TextToColumns`.

However, I did need to maintain my target range of column H for the `TextToColumns` as I needed it to start in the column it originated in instead of the column next to it.

Yes, I specifically made sure Column H matches that in Column A as the number of rows in the file is consistent within the file just not from file to file. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed your starting column intent and updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Sub WordSplit()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim r As Long

lastRow = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Count

    For r = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(r, 8) = "Words" Or Cells(r, 8) = "Words2" Then
        Else
            Cells(r, 8).TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(r, 8), 
            DataType:=xlDelimited,TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, 
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: While, this may work to meet a similar need it does completely change my original code instead of outline where changes need to be made. It appears the original purpose of maintaining the same number of rows across the file might be lost if you insert the above code for counting rows. There are blank cells in the column this applies to, not sure if this particular `lastRow` would include those or not include rows that used to have data, but have been deleted? The delimiter is a space delimiter instead of a double quote. Thanks for the input! Always great to see another possibility.